# Batch prepared statement auto commit

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to create multiple tables (upto 20) via `java.sql` prepared statement batch execute. Most of tables are related to eachother. But there is some confusion in my mind.

1) set connection auto commit true or false?
2) Is there any special pattern for BatchExecute.? like up down. I want to parent table create query must execute first.
3) If error ouccurs all the batch is rollback?

Comment: It is my understanding tha not in all RDBMS data definition language can be carried out in a transaction.

Comment: This seems a curious thing to do. If you want them all to role back then you should set autocommit to false. But messing around with database catalogs like this can cause problems.

Comment: so any better way for creating a tables. please suggest me.

Comment: Why do you want to create the tables?

Comment: There is a some table which is dependent for each user. when user is created a new table structure is created for him. There is a unique key also in table for particular user.

Comment: In reality, this will be driver and database specific, I would suggest you use normal Statements and do not use Batch. I would also suggest you rethink your solution, database catalogs invariably do not like being messed around with.

Comment: A 'table-per-user'-solution sounds like a design problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of batch execution with auto commit on is implementation defined, some drivers may not even support that. So if you want to use batch execution, set auto commit to false.

That said, some databases implicitly commit each DDL statement; this might interfere with correct working of batched execution. I would advise to take the safe route and not use batched execution for DDL, but to use a normal `Statement` and `execute(String)` for executing DDL.

Comment: one can open transaction explicitly and there is no need to control wether auto commit is enabled or not.

Comment: @SimonLogic That is not correct. In JDBC you can not explicitly start transactions, and you should not use native statements to start transactions as that can conflict with the driver auto-commit mode or break internal state of the driver. The only way to start transactions in the JDBC API is to disable auto-commit and then do something which requires a transaction (e.g. executing a statement). The driver will then start the transaction, and you will need to explicitly commit.

Comment: ok, i was thinking in context with tx aware services. in context of plain jdbc i see it must be disabled forever.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using batch execution in this case does not make much sense. Batch execution gives you a (big) performance improvement when inserting or updating thousands of rows at once.
You just need to have all your statements within a transaction:

1. call Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2. execute your create-table statements with Statement.executeUpdate
3. call Connection.commit()

You need to order the create-table statements yourself based on the foreign-keys between them.
As Mark pointed out, the DB you are using might commit each create-table right away and ignore the transaction. Not all DBs support transactional creation of tables. You will need to test this or do some more research regarding this aspect.